# What is west of Westeros?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *Game of Thrones S08E06*, we see

> Arya deciding to conclude her character arc in Westeros

and set sail to West of Westeros. Jon asks her what is there in West of Westeros & she replies with something like Nobody knows?

Do we know what lies beyond West of Westeros? Do we have anything to go by from A Song of Ice and Fire Or from A World of Ice and Fire or other supplementary books from GRRM?

Comment: Shush, don't give him spinoff ideas before he finishes writing A Song of Ice and Fire ;-)

Comment: Similar post from sister site[What is in the west of Westeros?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100921/what-is-in-the-west-of-westeros)

Comment: I shall think we will all find out the answer to this in HBO's spin off series.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Alton Greyjoy](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Alton_Greyjoy), [Elissa Farman](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Elissa_Farman), [Gylbert Farwynd](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Gylbert_Farwynd). It has long been the dream of the sea-farers of Westeros to discover the lands to the west. Even Queen Rhaenys wanted to go on that expedition on her dragon before she got caught up in war and was killed. Elissa Farman is the only one who _might_ have succeeded, if Corlys Velaryon was not mistaken but even then there's like 10% chance of her success.

Comment: A collection of small, beautiful islands called the West Asshais.

Comment: Easteros, eventually.